# Dynamic UI, Loop

Tags: c#, dynamic, user-interface

I created a dynamic UI that shows each module that the user has added to their selection and all the assessments for that module underneath the module name,
All data is saved in array lists - including objects as textBoxes and labels.

Here's what it looks like:
http://www.4shared.com/photo/fullsize/Ja3jHpRJ/screen1.html

Then the user should enter their marks for each assessments
And the Calculate button should calculate their overall mark for each module
At this stage I am just adding the marks together.
The program works fine when there's only one module added, but when there are more modules it seems to think that a TextBox is empty, even though i fill them all with numbers.

here is my code

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        int modLength = dat.ModuleTitle.Count;
        int modAsses = 0;
        int loopCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < modLength; i++)
        {

            int total = 0;

            if ((textboxComputer[loopCount] as TextBox).Text == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("!!!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                modAsses = int.Parse(dat.ModuleAssessNum[i].ToString());
                for (int y = 0; y < modAsses; y++)
                {

                    total = total + int.Parse((textboxComputer[loopCount] as TextBox).Text.ToString());

                    loopCount = loopCount + 1;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(total);
            }
        }
    }
```

When i add two or more modules it displays the "!!!!!" message, but calculates the mark for the first module added.

here's some output
http://www.4shared.com/photo/fullsize/PlY29BMQ/screen2.html

Comment: Parse without try/catch urg...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the code that creates the extra *dynamic* elements on screen is being called as part of the page load, so that then the viewstate is inserted back into the elements and can be read back out by your code.

Answer (score 0):

there is something wrong with your code, probably a lot wrong(except the names of your variables).

Take a look at your `loopCount` variable - you will only conditionally change it in your loop but you always use it at the start of the loop(where you do `textboxComputer[loopCount]`).

So what's the expected behavior of that? The first time you get in to the loop if you go to your 'else' part you may print the total as you say but you also change the loopCount variable, once you get to the `Console.WriteLine("!!!!!");` you never change it again - so your iterations will behave the same.

Comment: I can't see the reason my code goes to the Console.WriteLine("!!!!!"); at all, since none of the textboxes are empty, I add one to the loopCount every time it adds the value to "total" so it can then move on to the next textbox

Comment: Shouldn't you at least should set the loopCount = 0 when you move to the next module?

Comment: If i set it to 0 it is going to take the value from the first textbox in the array. Textboxes for all assessments are stored in the same array, added one by one when the assessments are displayed. The loopCount is just keeping track of which textbox value to take next.

Comment: ok, so there is one and only one assessment per module? the way the loop is written there cannot be more than one.

Comment: it goes in a loop for each module, then in that loop there is another loop for each assessment, loops through it depending on the number of assessments that module has and calculates the total mark. Then displays the mark for each module in the first loop, before it starts again. This works, but SOMETIMES it displays that "!!!!!"

Comment: Here is a case when the program works: 
http://www.4shared.com/photo/fullsize/ZkX_eJyC/screen3.html

And then after adding one more module: 
http://www.4shared.com/photo/fullsize/ChHqcV8B/screen4.html

Comment: Another Update: It's only doing that when I add a new module to the list after calculating the ones already added, if I add them all at once and then calculate it's all fine.